# prevent default is not working keeps refreshing the webpage and sendMessage is not working as well

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const sendMessage = async (event) => {
event.preventDefault();
    

<div className="chat_footer">
  <InsertEmoticonIcon />
  <form>
    <input value={input} onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)} placeholder="Type a message" type="text" />   
    <button onclick={sendMessage} type="submit">
      Send a message
    </button>
  </form>
  <MicIcon />
</div>
```

prevent default is not working keeps refreshing the webpage and sendMessage is not working as well

Comment: you need to prevent default on the form submit ... not the button click

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Ok so it’s not refreshing but it’s not submitting the typed message

Answer (score 0):

sendMessage, should be passed to onSubmit handler of the form element, as below.

```
const sendMessage = async (event) => {
event.preventDefault();
    
<div className="chat_footer">
<InsertEmoticonIcon/>
<form onSubmit={sendMessage}>
<input 
value={input} onChange={e => setInput(e.target.value)}
placeholder="Type a message"
type="text"
/>
    
<button type="submit">
Send a message
</button>
</form>
<MicIcon/>
</div>
```